# Angular is not setting the text from input to the model I assigned

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a JSON object with some keys and values. I want the user to be able to define what the values should be, so I generate some input boxes from the JSON object, using `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in argsJson">
         <label>{{key}}</label><input type="text" ng-model="val"/>
</div>
```

However, when I type in the input, it's not added to the model, as evidenced by an `alert` function I activate when I'm done typing.

```
$scope.makeAlert = function(){
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.argsJson));
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nx87fzo/1/

Comment: this is a typo issue. change `val` to `value`

Comment: @dcodesmith I changed both `val` to `value` and `value` to `val` and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `ng-model` from `val` to `argsJson[key]`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nx87fzo/2/) or code below. Also you had a typo (`val` and `value)` which [dcodesmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064206/dcodesmith) pointed out in the comments.

```
 <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in argsJson">
         <label>{{key}}</label><input type="text" ng-model="argsJson[key]"/>
     </div>
     <button ng-click="makeAlert()">Alert</button>
</div>
```